# Faulting module name: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll

Tags: windows, winui-3

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.22621.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>X</RootNamespace>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <DefaultLanguage>en</DefaultLanguage>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
    <WindowsPackageType>MSIX</WindowsPackageType>
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
 ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.5.240311000" />

</Project>
```

The [latest SDK](https://aka.ms/windowsappsdk/1.5/1.5.240311000/windowsappruntimeinstall-x64.exe) installed as the latest SDK nuget package.

I aim to debug the project but the Event Viewer exhibiting the error even if I first deploy the project and debug afterwards:

```
Faulting application name: x.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x65a80000
Faulting module name: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll, version: 3.1.5.0, time stamp: 0x7fd76c03
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000404495
Faulting process id: 0x0x17F8
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DA793E542F6342
Faulting application path: C:\Users\weath\source\repos\Weather.History\Weather.History.Windows\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\AppX\x.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\weath\source\repos\Weather.History\Weather.History.Windows\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\AppX\Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll
Report Id: 53b61667-909b-4964-b50a-a38a7723d309
Faulting package full name: Weather.History11_2.1.4.0_x64__qthhec8xancfe
```

[image]

WinDBG as Simon Mourier advised:

```
ModLoad: 00007fff`cc9b0000 00007fff`ccd96000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\D3DCOMPILER_47.dll
ModLoad: 00007fff`d0e20000 00007fff`d0e3b000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f51d0000 00007ffe`f523b000   C:\Users\weath\source\repos\Weather.History\Weather.History.Windows\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\AppX\Microsoft.InputStateManager.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f2f20000 00007ffe`f3088000   C:\Users\weath\source\repos\Weather.History\Weather.History.Windows\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\AppX\Microsoft.UI.Input.dll
ModLoad: 00007fff`d3c20000 00007fff`d3d74000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msctf.dll
Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll!00007FFEE68AD96E: 80040154 - Class not registered
(5f7c.18b4): Unknown exception - code c000027b (!!! second chance !!!)
```

Comment: Nobody here will be able help with such little information, we are not psychics who can read and debug binaries from a screenshot. You say *"Event Viewer exhibiting the error even if I first deploy the project and debug afterwards"*. If you start the process with a debugger (Visual Studio, WinDBG, etc.) you should get more information

Comment: 0x80040154 "Class not registered" means it's an installation/deployment issue. Have you installed the exact expected version of WinAppSDK runtime (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads). Or are you using an external COM object that is not registered?

Comment: I fetched /1.5/1.5.240311000/windowsappruntimeinstall-x64.exe and having nuget Version="1.5.240311000". now reinstalled and vcredist too, restarted VS but to no avail. There is no COM. Windows 11 latest SDK also installed.

Comment: If you don't use any COM object yourself, it means it's internal to WinUI3/WinAppSDK (activation of some internal objects). Can you put the project somewhere

Comment: Something wrong with the project files because a new template studio app is capable to launch. https://github.com/sigmarsson/78180962

Comment: It seems the same issue as https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7163.

Comment: Yes, obviously it's related to your code/binaries etc, but the solution on github is referencing a project that's not there.

Comment: @SimonMourier https://github.com/sigmarsson/SO78180962 shall now contain the missing shared project as well. - Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: App builds and runs fine for me (latest Windows 11), I get a maximized all-white window. But you use lots of external packages, this fragilizes your app, many can fail depending on your setup. Try to remove them one by one. I would try first to remove the low-level ThemeService thing. The problem is probably totally unrelated directly to WinUI3. You can also use Procmon (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what COM class is queried from (filter by your process and the registry)

Comment: @SimonMourier - Thanks. I removed `WinUICommunity.Components Version="6.5.0"` and `WinUICommunity.Core Version="6.5.0"` and the faulting error vanished. Then added those nugets again and updated to `6.6.0`. now it keeps working again. I do not understand.

Comment: Compute science is 5% magic